# Php script to fire another one after some amount of time

Tags: php, scheduled-tasks

I have a PHP script. I want this PHP script to trigger another PHP script under some condition, which I can do, but I want the second script to be fired after some amount of time..

For instance, if condition holds start the second script in 2 hours..

How can I achieve this in the simplest way using PHP or any other ready to use options?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a database with the time you need a script to be run and have a [cron](http://www.adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference) to run a php script every hour or so to check if there are tasks that needs to be performed (and perform them).

With that you could have your first php script to write the task, and the php script run by cron to finalize your task.

Comment: Thanks, this would be the easiest way for me.

Answer (score 2):

I think [Cronjob](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/managing-cron-jobs-with-php-2/) is what you need.
This link above should provide you with all info you may need to use it with PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Look into using `cronjobs`.

**Reference**: http://www.unixgeeks.org/security/newbie/unix/cron-1.html